# Show DIV content until another option is chosen

Tags: html, hide, show

I have a DIV that is used as my navbar. It will change out the content exactly how I like on click. However I would like my Product design content to initially show until another option is clicked.

STRICTLY CSS

HTML BELOW

```
<a href="#div1">PRODUCT DESIGN </a> | 
<a href="#div2">PRINT DESIGN</a> | 
<a href="#div3">LOGOS</a> | 
<a href="#div4">WEB DESIGN</a> | 
<a href="#div5">WEBSITES</a>

<div id="togg">
    <div id="div1">
PRODUCT DESIGN
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
PRINT DESIGN
    </div>

    <div id="div3">
LOGOS
    </div>

    <div id="div4">
WEB DESIGN
    </div>

    <div id="div5">
WEBSITES
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS BELOW

```
#togg > div {
    display: none;
}

#togg > div:target {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xkaaaylax/3d2m3fso/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`hide {
 display: none;
}`

`#div1 {
    display: block;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/fa2f8e00/

Comment: adding to this answer you will need javascript to change the div contents on navbar click

Comment: I was trying to avoid javascript all around, however that seems like it might not be an option. Can you please help with the solution to this if you are including Javascript.